# Remmina RDP certificate name mismatch error when trying to connect

Tags: 18.04, rdp, remmina

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on my local PC and I need to connect to a remote Windows 8.1 PC by rdp, using a VPN. I've managed to set up VPN correctly (MSCHAPv2, 128-bit with MPPE) and I can ping the remote machine (for example by its ip: 192.168.1.170).

I've set up latest Remmina for an rdp connection and filled all the connection parameters, but at the first connection attempt I get an error:

```
[23:04:24:341] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpdr
[23:04:24:354] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpsnd
[23:04:24:354] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr
[23:04:24:354] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx drdynvc
[23:04:24:619] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.crypto] - creating directory /home/bajiepka/snap/remmina/3223/.config/freerdp
[23:04:24:619] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.crypto] - creating directory [/home/bajiepka/snap/remmina/3223/.config/freerdp/certs]
[23:04:24:619] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.crypto] - created directory [/home/bajiepka/snap/remmina/3223/.config/freerdp/server]
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - Certificate verification failure 'unable to get local issuer certificate (20)' at stack position 0
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - CN = comp100
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - @           WARNING: CERTIFICATE NAME MISMATCH!           @
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - The hostname used for this connection (192.168.1.170:3389) 
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - does not match the name given in the certificate:
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - Common Name (CN):
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] -  comp100
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - A valid certificate for the wrong name should NOT be trusted!
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - The VerifyCertificate callback is deprecated, migrate your application to VerifyCertificateEx
[23:04:36:788] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.nla] - SPNEGO failed with NTSTATUS: 0xC0000192
[23:04:36:788] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error ERRCONNECT_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED [0x00020009]
[23:04:36:788] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.rdp] - rdp_recv_callback: CONNECTION_STATE_NLA - nla_recv_pdu() fail
[23:04:36:788] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - transport_check_fds: transport->ReceiveCallback() - -1

(org.remmina.Remmina:10334): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:04:36.934: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:8584: widget not within a GtkWindow
```

As far as I understand from log output, the problem comes from a missing certificate that should be in a directory `/home/bajiepka/snap/remmina/3223/.config/freerdp/certs`

Further attempts show similar errors:

```
[23:06:15:385] [10334:10667] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpdr
[23:06:15:385] [10334:10667] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpsnd
[23:06:15:385] [10334:10667] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr
[23:06:15:386] [10334:10667] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx drdynvc
[23:06:15:435] [10334:10667] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - Certificate verification failure 'unable to get local issuer certificate (20)' at stack position 0
[23:06:15:435] [10334:10667] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - CN = comp100
[23:06:15:462] [10334:10667] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.nla] - SPNEGO failed with NTSTATUS: 0xC0000192
[23:06:15:463] [10334:10667] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error ERRCONNECT_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED [0x00020009]
[23:06:15:463] [10334:10667] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.rdp] - rdp_recv_callback: CONNECTION_STATE_NLA - nla_recv_pdu() fail
[23:06:15:463] [10334:10667] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - transport_check_fds: transport->ReceiveCallback() - -1

(org.remmina.Remmina:10334): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:06:15.570: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:8584: widget not within a GtkWindow
```

Can I generate this certificate manually, or did I miss anything about this certificate usage??? How can I solve this connection problem?

Comment: Some questions: 1) How are you connecting to the remote server? In Remmina, what are you putting into the 'server' field? 2) How are you authenticating? Are you authenticating using a username/password, or using some kind of certificate authentication?

Comment: Longer comment: This error message "The hostname used for this connection (192.168.1.170:3389) does not match the name given in the certificate: Common Name (CN): `comp100`" means the following- You are trying to to connect to the remote compute `192.168.1.170:3389`, and when you do so, the remote computer returns to you (Remmina) a certificate it has. This certificate lists a Common Name (CN) of `comp100`. This means the certificate is only valid for computers with the name `comp100`, and not named `192.168.1.170`.

Comment: I had similar issue but with using xfreerdp client. When I was connecting to windows server using external domain name it said `Certificate verification failure 'unable to get local issuer certificate (20)' at stack position 0`, but when I've tried to connect using its public IP address it connected however, CN of certificate was internal FQDN, not IP.